# PHP Pascal's Triangle table?

Tags: php, arrays, output

I am currently programming Pascal's triangle and have 2 problems:

Why do the cells in my case have different widths, and what is the easiest way that it also looks like a Pascal's triangle and not everything is left-aligned?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pascal'sches Dreieck</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#DDDDDD text=#0000AA>

<form action="<?php $PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
<pre>
eingabe:   <input type="text" name = "eingabe" size="4">


<input type="submit" name="schalter" value="OK">
</pre>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["schalter"])){
    
    $eingabe = $_POST["eingabe"];
    
    
    print "<table class=\"table\">";
    
    for($zeile = 1; $zeile <= $eingabe; $zeile++){ //Zeilen
        print "<tr>";
        for($spalte = 1; $spalte <= $zeile; $spalte++){ //Spalten
            if($spalte == 1 OR $spalte == $zeile){
                $array[$zeile][$spalte] = 1;
                print "<th class=\"zellen\">".$array[$zeile][$spalte]."</th>";                  
            }

            else{
                $array[$zeile][$spalte] = $array[$zeile-1][$spalte-1] + $array[$zeile-1][$spalte];                  
                print "<th class=\"zellen\">".$array[$zeile][$spalte]."</th>";                  
            }               
        }   
    }
    print "</tr></table>";   
}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Because you didnt tell the TD how wide it should be

Comment: Okay, thanks,  and how I fix the left-align?

Comment: Add in the appropriate number of empty cells at the start a row of cells. Something like: `echo '<td colspan='.floor(0.5*($eingabe-$zeile)).'></td>';`. It might be off by one, but you can adjust that.